# When do $q promises resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a following piece of code:

```
function getData(foos, bars) {
  var generated = {};

  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {

    var promises = _.map(foos, function(foo) {
      return _.map(bars, function(bar) {
        return someServiceCall(foo, bar).then(function(data) {
            _.set(generated[foo.id], player.id.toString() + '.data', data);
          });
      });
    });

    // Join all promises in to a final resolve
    $q.all(promises).then(function() {
      resolve(generated);
    }, reject);
  });
}
```

What I want to achieve is to have all the `someServiceCall`-s and it's success handlers finished by the time `resolve(generated)` is called. When I debug this part of the code in the developer toolbar, `resolve(generated)` is called before the success handler of `someServiceCall` is called for every promise.

Note: This not always breaks the functionality, as the objects are passed as a reference, so the data is set even if resolve was already called, but I think the functionality would be clearer if all those calls were finished by the time resolve is called.

Answer (score 3):

I just realized my dumb mistake. The two nested maps resulted the following structure:

```
var promises = [[Promise, Promise][Promise, Promise, Promise]];
```

While `$q.all` expects an array of promises:

```
var promises = [Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise];
```

I could easily solve this by replacing the first `map` call by `flatMap`:

```
return _.flatMap(bars, function(bar) {
```

It's still strange for me that `$q.all` silently just resolved the promise without an error or warning that the data format is not appropriate.

I hope I can help someone who runs into this problem in the future.